# C function call segmentation fault

Tags: c, function, segmentation-fault

I'm experiencing a segfault when recursing a pointer function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func(int(*function)()) {
    (*function)();
    func(function);
};

int function() {

};

int main() {
    func(function);
};
```

When compiled and executed, the recursive function calls last for a few cycles and then throw a segfault. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: How does it stop?

Comment: Update: simply adding -O2 to the gcc args fixed it

Comment: it may be that the optimizer simply removes your code all together. Since it has no visible effects its liable to be elided completely. If it runs it will run forever.

Answer (score 1):

More likely than not, you simply ran out of space in your stack frame because your function will recurse forever.